# How to prioritize mavenLocal over artifactory repo in gradle?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I have multi-modules project and I'm using artifactory for resolving custom libraries:
`build.gradle` of parent project:

```
...
subporjects {
   ...
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

    artifactory {
        resolve {
            contextUrl = ext.getProperty('ARTIFACTORY_URL')
            repoKey = ext.getProperty('ARTIFACTORY_REPO_NAME')
            username = ext.getProperty('ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME')
            password = ext.getProperty('ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD')
        }
    }
}
```

It works as expected my library is published to artifactory with `gradle artifactoryPublish` and then it's fetched from there. But in some cases I want to fetch my custom library from `mavenLocal()` repo. I have next subproject `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'my-custom-library'
}
```

But as I can see it is still resolves from artifactory. Can I somehow prioritize `mavenLocal()` over it ?

Comment: The library which you have in maven local should be a copy of the one used in artifactory. If they are different, you should be using different versions.

Answer (score 1):

The repository priority will be the order in which they were added to the [RepositoryHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html)

I'm guessing that the artifactory repository is added when the plugin is applied so you could delay this by

```
afterEvaluate {
    subprojects {
        apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
        // etc
    }
}
```

Or maybe

```
evaluationDependsOnChildren()
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to depend on one subproject from within another, you should declare dependencies using the `project` notation:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies